# Camera Orientation Doesn't Follow the Device Orientation when the Screen Rotation is Turned Off

Tags: unity-game-engine, flutter, dart, augmented-reality

As per the title, I have an AR game embedded in the flutter app that I want to run in landscape mode.
I tried using this code:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);
  }
```

And it did work to set the screen orientation to landscape, but the problem is when the screen rotation is turned off in my phone settings, the background in AR mode starts showing the upside-down view from the camera, which looks a bit weird from the user experience perspective.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Why have you embedded your unity game into a flutter app ? I'm curious. Because Unity supports device orientation, and it's configurable inside preferences (lock or not)

Comment: Cause I have created the app with flutter first and I wanna add game into it. I know now days you can even create an app with unity but I have just already made it in flutter.

Comment: ...because you turned screen rotation off.

Comment: @Draco18snolongertrustsSE yes that's right, cause that is what probably the user setting in their phone. That's why I wanna catch this issue.

Comment: This is a PEBKAC issue. Its literally not your problem.